# npm install testcafe --save-dev give vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm-install, testcafe

I'm new to testcafe and when I run npm install testcafe --save-dev, I get the following errors. I tried installing testcafe@15.1.317922 which it says is the fix but I get even more vulnerabilities...not sure what to do here! Thanks!

async  <2.6.4

Severity: high

Prototype Pollution in async - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fwr7-v2mv-hh25
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install testcafe@15.1.317922, which is a breaking change
node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/async

testcafe-legacy-api  <=5.1.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of async
node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-legacy-api

testcafe  <=1.18.6-rc.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of testcafe-legacy-api
node_modules/testcafe

3 high severity vulnerabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already addressed this issue:

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-legacy-api/issues/59.

The next minor TestCafe update will include this fix.